# It is possible to set an image background to repeat in apple watch?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-watch

I have this source:

```
import Foundation
import WatchKit

class MyController: WKInterfaceController {


@IBOutlet weak var button: WKInterfaceButton!
   
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
   super.awakeWithContext(context)
  
    let gradientBlue = UIImage(named: "80x1blueback")
    let colorBlue = UIColor(patternImage: gradientBlue!)

    self.button.setColor(colorBlue)
   }

}
```

Every variable takes value and the call to:

```
self.button.setColor(colorBlue)
```

success. But, after that it crash.

> libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill:
> 0x10a6a3278:  movl   $0x2000148, %eax
>
> 0x10a6a327d:  movq   %rcx, %r10
>
> 0x10a6a3280:  syscall
>
> 0x10a6a3282:  jae    0x10a6a328c               ; __pthread_kill + 20
>
> 0x10a6a3284:  movq   %rax, %rdi
>
> 0x10a6a3287:  jmp    0x10a69eca3               ; cerror_nocancel
>
> 0x10a6a328c:  retq
>
> 0x10a6a328d:  nop
>
> 0x10a6a328e:  nop
>
> 0x10a6a328f:  nop

Marker from Xcode stops at:

> 0x10a6a3282:  jae    0x10a6a328c               ; __pthread_kill + 20

The app, keeps running on the watch but this view never gets visible.
My image is of 80pixels height, 1 pixel width.

I did test this source on iOS and it works perfectly. So I think it must be something regarding the watch.

Comment: When I call to self.button.setColor(UIColor.brownColor()) it works like charm. The problem appears to be with dinamically created colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, although not seems to be possible this way. Actually, it's easier, just that you are not going to see any results on Storyboard and that can make you think that's a no go.
This is how:

> 1.- Set your "image to repeat" (In my case: "80x1blueback" ) on assets of the Watchkit app, (not the extension)
>
> 2.- Set your image as the Background of the button (It will not be visible)
>
> 3.- Set your Height to anything but "Size to Fit" option.

That's All, Compile and run!